# Is $n! \sum_{i=0}^n{\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}- (n-1)! \bigg[\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}{\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}+...+\sum_{i=0}^{2}{\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}\bigg]=(n-1)!$ true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation, self-learning, factorial

I am in the middle of doing a problem and has this sort of expression. I have a feeling that the following equality holds:
$$n! \sum_{i=0}^n{\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}- (n-1)! \bigg[\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}{\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}{\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-4}{\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}+...+\sum_{i=0}^{2}{\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}\bigg]=(n-1)!$$

Does the above identity hold?

If it is, how we can show it?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Object i is showing $n!$ in the first number and $i\cdot (n-1)!$ times in the second so the identity don't hold.

Comment: This fails to be true for $n=2$, so I suppose that the formula is not correct.

Comment: @Crostul I think it holds for $n=2$ since all the terms in the square bracket will gone, and we're left with $2! \sum_{i=0}^2 \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} = 2!(1/2!) = 1 = (2-1)!$

Comment: For $n=2$ in the square bracket it remains $\sum_{i=0}^0 (-1)^i/i! = 1$.

Comment: @Crostul Right. But, I think what the OP's trying to say is $\sum_{j=2}^{n-2} \sum_{i=0}^j \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the identity is valid. Dividing OPs expression by $n!$ and putting the bracketed sum to the right we show

> The following is valid for $n> 0$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^n}{i!}=\frac{1}{n}\left(1+\sum_{j=2}^{n-2}\sum_{i=0}^j\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\right)
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> We obtain starting with the RHS
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{n}&\left(1+\sum_{j=2}^{n-2}\sum_{i=0}^j\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\sum_{i=0}^j\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\sum_{j=i}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}(n-i-1)\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{(i-1)!}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}-\frac{1}{n}\frac{(-1)^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}\tag{6}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(n-1)\tag{7}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim is finished.

**Comment:**

- In (1) we observe that $$1=\sum_{j=0}^{1}\sum_{i=0}^j\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$
- In (2) we exchange the sums by noting that $$0\leq i\leq j\leq n-2$$
- In (3) we see the inner sum indexed with $j$ is $n-i-1$
- In (4) we split the sum according to $n-1-i$ and observe that in the middle sum the term  with $i=0$ vanishes
- In (5) we shift the index of the middle sum by one and prepare so for telescoping
- In (6) we use telescoping
- In (7) we expand with $\frac{n-1}{n-1}$

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your LHS this way: $$LHS = n! \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} - (n-1)!\left(\sum_{j=2}^{n-2} \sum_{i=0}^j \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\right) \\
= n! \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} - (n-1)!\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-2} \sum_{i=0}^j \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} - 1\right)$$
Swapping sums gives:
$$LHS = n! \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} - (n-1)!\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \sum_{j=i}^{n-2} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} - 1\right) \\ 
= n! \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} - (n-1)!\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} (n-1-i) \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} - 1\right) \\
= n! \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} - \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} (n-1)!(n-1-i) \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} + (n-1)! \\
= (-1)^n (1 - n) + n! \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} - \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} (n-1)!(n-1-i) \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} + (n-1)! \\
= (-1)^n (1 - n) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} \left[ n! - (n-1)!(n-1-i) \right] + (n-1)! \\
= \underbrace{(-1)^n (1 - n) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}(n-1)!(1+i)}_A + (n-1)!$$

Can you now show that $A = 0$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this identity would be equivalent to the following. If the original expression is true then the following holds:

$ \frac{\Gamma(n+1,-1)}{\Gamma(n)} = e+\sum_{k=2}^n {\frac{\Gamma(k+1,-1)}{\Gamma(k+1)}}$

I am not sure, however, if the original identity in the question is true.

Comment: I will run some computer verifications for small $n$ as soon as I get to a computer. I have a suspicion that n=6 fails in the original equation but need to verify that rough educated-guess.